# After Anaconda upgrade PyCharm begins indexing and never ends

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, anaconda

Today I upgraded my Anaconda distribution to Anaconda3. After that, PyCharm
started indexing and its been at it for hours.

At the bottom-right of the window there is a progress bar that looks like this:
[image]

The number on the left - "247" in the image goes up and down. I have no clue what the 247 or the 725 mean.

(Since I wrote this I found out that the first number is the current heap size and the second is the maximum).

I'm aware that sometimes PyCharm goes on an indexes things live venvs or other directories it shouldn't, but AFIAK I don't have any such thing; This is the structure of the project:
[image]

Any idea of what's going on? I upgraded Anaconda before without a problem.

Comment: You ever figure this out?

Comment: Eventually it stopped. It was paging like crazy and this was before I upgraded memory 4GB->8GB and changed the hard disk to an SSD.

Comment: No solution?  It's indexing the entire anaconda folder.  Is it supposed to do that?